# meaning of "mugging away ?"

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of  "mugging away ?"

Can anyone help me with this ?

I know mugging merely means attack on someone  in public places to steal something .

But what is the meaning when it become as a phrase like this "mugging away?"

Comment: Do you have some example sentences in which you have seen/heard "mugging away"? Is it possible that you've actually seen "mugging away at"? If it's actually "mugging away at", it probably means the same thing as [_mug up_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mug_up).

Comment: @  senshin Agreed. It's the sort of wacky mangling of the language Wodehouse was so brilliant at: _[Wooster]: 'What ho, Fink-Nottle Junior. What're you up to?' _[F-N J] 'Just mugging up on the breeding patterns of Siamese newts, Uncle Bertie.' _[BW] 'Excellent! Mug away, my boy, mug away!'

Comment: Few weeks back when i asked one of my UK friend 'how are you doing'? he replied " not much I am mugging around" i am still trolled what exactly she meant.

Comment: @senshin I can only find the robbery definition of 'mugging' on line but I'm sure people used to use 'mugging up' in the same sense as you have 'mug up' even if it's no longer current. I'd still use it but that probably says more about my age than anything else. Perhaps the OP needs to give us a bit more context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it totally lacks context (and the meaning of "mugging" is highly context-dependent).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, "mugging" has two meanings:

1) an act of violence with the intent to rob [noun definition here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mugging)

2) using one's face to get attention or pose for a picture [third noun definition of "mug" here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mugging)

"Mugging away" only makes sense in meaning 2 above:

Example: "The playful boy continued mugging away as his mother tried to figure out her camera and take a picture."

I don't know the context of your question. Without context, this is the best I can do.